# Workflow using Run Command Shell

Tags: macos, terminal, shell

I am trying run an rysnc command to syncronise some files and folder through workflow but i can not run this command if i am logged in as a non-admin user. Can someone please advise a command which would excute through a non admin user??

Thanks

Comment: Since `osx` is based on `FreeBSD`, you might be able to use linux's chown command then run it after that. Doing some googling I found: http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/23/change-file-ownership-mac-os-x/ hope leads you down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

If by "workflow" you are referring to an Automator-type task, you would either have to pass the admin credentials in your script or setup a Launch Agent as that user to do this. There are many discussions on SuperUser for Launch Agent configs or you can check [Apple's Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) for more info).

But if you mean a process, you can use the admin account's crontab to run your rsync script.

Comment: can you suggest any command?
I am using the following command through workflow 
"rsync -aE --delete /source /destination"